# C# Linq entity query syntax. Return count for So that you can assign to the table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to assign an var query value to a (DataGrid)dgEntity without DataTable
How can i do it?

```
var query = (from c in db.CUSTOMERS.Local
                            let avg = (from o2 in db.CITIES.Local
                                       join o3 in db.CUSTOMERS.Local on o2.CITNUM equals o3.CITNUM
                                       where (o2.CITY == "Ярославль")
                                       select new { o3.RATING }).Average(t => t.RATING)
                            where (c.RATING>avg)
                            select new
                            {
                               cusnum = c.CUSNUM
                            }).Count();
                DataTable d = new DataTable();
                d.Columns.Add("Count");
                d.Rows.Add(new object[] { query });
                dgEntity.ItemsSource = d.DefaultView;
```

Comment: mistake in header
to the table => to the DataGrid

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something the result of Count() is getting assigned to query which is just an int and not enumerable. Can you try taking Count() off of the linq query?

Comment: No, i need a count objects in collection move to DataGrid without DataTable